# Build/Run Elasticsearch Locally with plugins

Tags: elasticsearch, plugins

(On Elasticsearch version 6.5.1)

How can I build/run Elasticsearch from source with local plugins?

I've tried the following command to install the plugins: 
`./distribution/build/cluster/run\ node0/elasticsear-6.5.1-SNAPSHOT/bin/elasticsearch-plugin install file:/<path_to_plugin_zip>` and that says it successfully installed the plugin.

However, when I run elasticsearch via `./gradlew run --debug-jvm`, it cleans out the contents of that directory before running ES.

The reason I installed the plugin into that particular directory is that I put a debugger in the PluginsService.java file, and saw that the `Path pluginsDirectory` parameter in the constructor was set to `/Users/jreback/Desktop/elasticsearch/distribution/build/cluster/run node0/elasticsearch-6.5.1-SNAPSHOT/plugins`.

So, how can I get my plugin installed on my local ES version and run ES such that the plugin code doesn't get removed as the process starts up? Many thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1):

FWIW, I got this working with some manual code changes (there may be or likely is a more recommended way to do this, but this worked for me).

In my ES checkout, I made the following code change to `server/src/main/java/org/elasticsearch/env/Environment.java`:

- replace this line: `pluginsFile = homeFile.resolve("plugins");` with `pluginsFile = Paths.get("<path to plugin directory");`
  (Also, you must `import java.nio.file.Paths` at the top of that file).

The directory structure for the directory you listed above should look like this:

```
- plugin parent directory (should whatever you put in the Environment.java file)
    - plugin directory (name of the plugin)
        - plugin-descriptor.properties file
        - plugin jar file (generated from building the plugin in some prior step)
```

Then you should see that it loaded the plugin you've just added in the logs when you start up ES again.